# Vagrant sahara plugin - multiple snapshots

Tags: vagrant

How I can make more than one snapshot when in sahara sandbox mode?
Or, can I see list of all commits I've ever made and rollback to any?

#### Why do I need all this?

I just want to setup initial VM. After that I want to compile number of packages from sources, and this takes pretty long time. So right now I thinking of this order:

1. Setup initial ubuntu 12.04 vagrant box
2. Snapshot this state
3. Compile sources, install system wide rbenv (it make compilation also)
4. Snapshot second state
5. Start all my infrastructure experiments
6. Rollback to any of my previous states or commit third state

Answer (score 1):

This workflow isn't supported by Sahara. Each time you run `vagrant sandbox commit`, it deletes your previous snapshot and creates a new one. If you want to preserve multiple snapshots, have to manage them manually. If you're using Virtualbox, [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp58626624) is the relevant documentation.

One thing you could consider is, after step 3, [packaging](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/packaging.html) the state of your VM into a box. That way you easily create and destroy VMs for your experiments without having to repeat steps 1 - 3.